# Multiple IFERROR commands not working between 2 sheets

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to create a proper function code in excel 2010 that allows information from a schedule (4 days) to flow to a main schedule depending on the date.  'Main' page (sheet 1) has E1 pulling current date directly from computer. 'Beauty Shop' page has  manually entered date in B3, D3, F3 and H3 and if the dates match the information from A& B5-24, C&D5-24, E&F5-24, G&H5-24 respectively are suppose to pull to the main schedule.  At this point A&B will pull but when the other columns (D3, F3 and H3) have the matching date to main E1 the information from  C&D5-24, E&F5-24, G&H5-24 will not pull ... Here is what we entered

=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$B$3,'Beauty Shop'!A5>0),'Beauty Shop'!A5," "),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$D$3,'Beauty Shop'!C5>0),'Beauty Shop'!C5),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$F$3,'Beauty Shop'!E5>0),'Beauty Shop'!E5),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$H$3,'Beauty Shop'!G5>0),'Beauty Shop'!G5)," "))))

Any suggestions as to why the other 3 functions are not pulling the information to the main schedule??

Here is a link to what we have so far  ...This one should work...If you open it with Zoho sheet it will show all formulas and how we set everything up at this point.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wFNip-EvKdaXhVRDlnQzdQUzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not the downvote but your description of your setup is too imprecise to be able to understand what's going on. Can you provide screenshots of the sheets and/or give sample cell values+formulae in your question? Even better, upload a copy of your spreadsheet somewhere which stores files permanently (so future visitors can benefit from this question) and include a link.

Comment: I have added a link to the entire work book.  Thank you for the advice, I am new at this and any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Good effort, unfortunately, that download link doesn't work (probably it works for you because you're logged in and the account owner). You may be able to find some alternative sites to use here: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/feature/storage/top-20-cloud-storage-services-3421715/

Comment: Thanks Again!!!  I tried a different link and it looks like if you open it with Zoho sheet you can see everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're after but let's see if this helps...

From the spreadsheet you uploaded, and assuming you're referring to the formula in A47 on the main sheet...

`=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$B$3,'Beauty Shop'!A5>0),'Beauty Shop'!A5," "),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$D$3,'Beauty Shop'!C5>0),'Beauty Shop'!C5),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$F$3,'Beauty Shop'!E5>0),'Beauty Shop'!E5),IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$H$3,'Beauty Shop'!G5>0),'Beauty Shop'!G5)," "))))`

LibreOffice's helpful formula editor shows the following for the start of your expression tree...

[image]

Let's ignore the `IFERROR`s for now and look at your first `IF`...

`IF(AND($E$1=$'Beauty Shop'.$B$3,$'Beauty Shop'.A6>0),$'Beauty Shop'.A6," ")`

In short...

If Main's E1 (Today's date) = Beauty Shop's B3 AND Beauty Shop's A6 is more than 0 (A time other than midnight), Return the value of Beauty Shop's A6 (The time). **Otherwise, return an empty string**.

The second `IF` block will only be executed if the first one errors, not if it returns false.

So the simple fix is to remove the blank string and move the following blocks up one level.

At the very least, make sure your strings aren't empty while debugging - it will make it a lot easier to track where your logic flow ends up.

EDIT: I previously said you could do this with a single IFERROR but that was incorrect.

Hope that helps a little

#### A simpler approach...

Let's use some hidden cells for some intermediate values to represent which data to pull.

Put the following formulae in `Main.H1:K1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1=$'Beauty Shop'.$B3,$'Beauty Shop'.A5 > 0), 1, 0), 0)
=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1=$'Beauty Shop'.$D3,$'Beauty Shop'.C5 > 0), 1, 0), 0)
=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1=$'Beauty Shop'.$F3,$'Beauty Shop'.E5 > 0), 1, 0), 0)
=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1=$'Beauty Shop'.$H3,$'Beauty Shop'.G5 > 0), 1, 0), 0)
```

These cells will now contain a 1 or 0 indicating the values should be populated. You can repeat these down the page.

The reason to do this is that there are 2 cases resulting in a 0 (No data and an error) so doing it all in one go would either require repeating the ELSE branch multiple times or doing some maths with the resulting values (which works and is concise but is very hard to follow/maintain)

Then your formula for `Main.A47` becomes...

```
=IF(H1, $'Beauty Shop'.A5,IF(I1, $'Beauty Shop'.C5,IF(J1, $'Beauty Shop'.E5,IF(K1, $'Beauty Shop'.G5,""))))
```

See below for how today's value is matching (`K1` is a 1) which has caused it to pull a record from the Beauty shop page.

[image]

Hope that's clearer?

Comment: Thank You so much for your quick response.  So your saying take out the " "    ??

Comment: Yes-ish. You can't just remove the " " as there has to be an ELSE. You've got 3 outcomes for each day - Correct day, Incorrect Day, Error. Is there a particular error that caused you to add the `IFERROR`s? If not, I'd remove all the IFERRORs entirely and just have `IF(<Monday and Valid Time>, Monday's Schedule, IF(<Tuesday and Valid Time>, Tuesday's Schedule, ...etc... )`. If there's a reason to expect errors (eg someone typing a name instead of a time), You would need to duplicate the ELSE. Something like... `IFERROR(IF(Monday, Show Monday, Check Tuesday), Check Tuesday)` ... (cont)

Comment: This is going to make your formula much more complex. Personally, I'd consider breaking this down into multiple steps which are easier to debug/maintain. (Have a hidden cell for each weekday that indicates if it's "today" and there are no errors). Then your current formula only needs to check which of those hidden fields is True to determine which values to show. I'm heading out the door to work so can't put together a tested example but I'll check back in later today and see what I can do if nobody beats me to it

Comment: Ok, have a look at the edit from "A simpler approach" and let me know if that helps

Comment: You were right!!! This works.   Thank you once again you saved me from a tremendous amount of work and headaches!!!           This is what I ended up with                                                                            =IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$B$3,'Beauty Shop'!A5>0),'Beauty Shop'!A5,IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$D$3,'Beauty Shop'!C5>0),'Beauty Shop'!C5,IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$F$3,'Beauty Shop'!E5>0),'Beauty Shop'!E5,IFERROR(IF(AND($E$1='Beauty Shop'!$H$3,'Beauty Shop'!G5>0),'Beauty Shop'!G5,""),"")),"")),""))

Comment: Took out the first IFERROR and added ''"),"")),"")),"")) at the end

Comment: Nice, glad I could help. If you consider my answer a solution, please accept it with the tick on the left and consider upvoting when you have enough rep. If not, post your own answer with all the details and accept that